# saveACopy in ArcPy, failed to save document

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, copy, save

I have a script that saves a copy of the current .mxd to a location given to the script by a user. However I keep getting an error that says it failed to save the document.

I have writing rights in the folder and I have tried different locations as well, which doesn't seem to work either.

I don't seem to be able to find what I am missing, would anyone be able to tell me where I am going wrong? I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

**Old code**:

```
import arcpy

import arcpy.mapping as map

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Folder_location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

mxd.saveACopy(r"{}\{}\{}.mxd".format(Folder_location, Project_number, Project_number))


del mxd
```

I have changed my code a bit with the help of the comments underneath. It works fine when I put a string for *"Project_number"* and *"Folder_location"*. However when I set it as a parameter, it fails to save.

The parameters would be this:

Folder_location: *U:\Example*

Project_number: *test*

So, when I put these in the script as strings, they work. But when I set these as parameters to be chosen when the script starts (with the exact same data) it fails.

Any ideas?

**New code:**

```
import arcpy

import arcpy.mapping as map

import os

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Folder_location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Corrected = os.path.normcase(Folder_location)
MXD = ".mxd"
MXDName = Project_number + MXD
Pathname = os.path.join(Corrected, Project_number, MXDName)
CPath = os.path.normcase(Pathname)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

mxd.saveACopy(CPath)

del mxd
```

Comment: What does `print r"{}\{}\{}.mxd".format(Folder_location, Project_number, Project_number)` output? Ok looking path+filename?

Comment: I set Project_number as "test" and Folder_location as "U:\" for this test. It is supposed to print "U:\test\test", but it comes back as "test/test/test".

Comment: Try using os.path.join instead of format to combine path and filename

Comment: Python best practice is to use `os.path.join` to assemble paths. What does `print(os.path.join(Folder_location, Project_number, "{}.mxd".format(Project_number)))` return?

Comment: The os.path.join option seems to be working, there is however one issue. The user will be able to select a folder, which is written away as a string as such: "U:\Examplefolder". The Project_number is then a folder after the "Examplefolder" aswel as the .mxd name. The "os.path.join" doesn't like the "\" in "U:\Examplefolder", is there a way to work around this? Seeing as the "U:\Examplefolder" is one string and Id prefer to keep it that way, so the user only has to select 1 item.

Comment: If you have a backslash in a string with is not escaped properly, it becomes an escape character for the following character. This is a generic Python issue. Any tool which offers a choice of strings needs its input correctly encoded, or it just passes the problem down the line.

Comment: I have added some more information, as the problem is now a bit different after editing my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved by using os.path.join() as stated in the code below. The other issue I had with this code was a dumb copy and paste overlook.

```
import arcpy

import arcpy.mapping as map

import os

Project_number = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Folder_location = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Corrected = os.path.normcase(Folder_location)
MXD = ".mxd"
MXDName = Project_number + MXD
Pathname = os.path.join(Corrected, Project_number, MXDName)
CPath = os.path.normcase(Pathname)

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

mxd.saveACopy(CPath)

del mxd
```